# Getting summary statistics from a class

Tags: python

I am coding in Python and I have to code in a class that takes a list of numbers and returns the size of the list, the mean of the list, and the min and max of the list

```
list_1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
class SummaryStats:
    def __init__(self, list_x):
        self.list_x = list_x
        #self.mean = sum(list_x) / len(list_x)
        #self.min = min(list_x)
        #self.max = max(list_x)

    def sample_size(list_x):
        """
        (list) -> int
        
        Takes in a list of data points x and returns the number of observations.
        """
        return len(list_x)
    
    def sample_mean(list_x):
        """
        (list) -> float
        
        Takes in a list of data points x and returns the aritnmetic mean of the list.
    
        """
        mean_x = sum(list_x) / len(list_x)
        return mean_x
    
    def minimum(list_x):
        """
        (list) -> float
    
        Takes in a list of data points x and returns the minimum of the list.
        """    
        return min(list_x)
    
    def maximum(list_x):
        """
        (list) -> float
    
        Takes in a list of data points x and returns the maximum of the list.
        """    
        return max(list_x)
list_1 = SummaryStats()
print(sample_size(list_1), sample_mean(list_1), minimum(list_1), maximum(list_1))
list_2 = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
list_2 = SummaryStats(list_2)
print(list_2.size, list_2.mean, list_2.min, list_2.max)
```

What I currently have

Comment: There are slightly different solutions depending on whether you want the mean, min and max to be methods or calculated properties, but in all cases, the first parameter for each would be self, and you probably wouldn't pass list_x as a parameter.  Instead, you would reference self.list_x

Answer (score 1):

For `len`, `max` and `min` you need to need to write a method. You can archive like this,

```
class SummaryStats:
    def __init__(self, list_x):
        self.size = len(list_x)
        self.mean = self.sample_mean(list_x)
        self.min = min(list_x)
        self.max = max(list_x)
    
    def sample_mean(self, list_x):
        return sum(list_x) / len(list_x)
    
list_2 = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
l2 = SummaryStats(list_2)
print(l2.size, l2.mean, l2.min, l2.max)
```

Output:

```
8 11.5 8 15
```